# Number of chords in a $n$-gon if each chord is crossed at most $k$ times

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, polygons

Consider an $n$-gon where we denote the points by $v_1, \dots, v_n$.
If we allow each chord (internal edge of the $n$-gon) to have at most $k$ crossings, how many chords can we put into the $n$-gon (denoted as $c(n,k)$).
The answer to this question is the density of outer-$k$-planar graphs (+ n for the boundary edges of the $n$-gon):
For $k = 0$, we have at most $n-3$ chords.
For $k = 1$, we have $1.5n - 4$.
One can show that $2n-5$ and $2.25n-6$ holds for $k = 2$ and $3$.
Can we generalize this to any $k$?:

Chaplick et al.[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbbWX.png) showed that outer-$k$-planar graphs are $d$-degenerate with $d = \lfloor \sqrt{4k+1}+1 \rfloor$, hence we have less than $dn \approx 2\sqrt{k}n$ chords.

Now the best lower bound I can think of (and I  suspect to be best possible) only has approximately $\sqrt{k}n$ chords (hence, the upper bound would be off by a factor of $2$).

Alternative views of the problem:

1. Consider the adjacency matrix $A$ of an outer-$k$-planar graph. $A$ is symmetric, binary, has only zeroes in the diagonal and ones in the off-diagonal. Now if there exists an edge $(v_i,v_j)$, we have at most $k$ edges that are incident to $v_p$ with $ i < p < j$ and $v_q$ with $q < i$ or $j < q$, hence we have at most $k$ 1-entries in the marked areas, see Figure below.

[[image: Adjacency matrix of <span class=]$okp$ graphs" />](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbbWX.png)

2. We can consider the intersection graph $IG$ of the graph, i.e. every possible chord is a node of $IG$ and it is connected to another node in $IG$ iff the respective chords in $G$ intersect. Then, the problem is to find a maximum induced subgraph in $IG$ such that the degree is bounded by $k$. This problem is in general known to be NP-hard, but maybe this can be solved for our particular graph. (Note that this somehow has to be extended to any $n$).

One can solve this problem for small $n$ and $k$ with an integer linear programm which yields

\begin{array}{c|rrrrrrrrrrrrr}
{_n\,\backslash\, ^k} & 0 & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & 7 & 8 & 9 & 10 & 11 & 12 \\
\hline
4 & 1 & 2 & & & & & & & & & & & \\
5 & 2 & 3 & 5 & & & & & & & & & & \\
6 & 3 & 5 & 6 & 8 & 9 & & & & & & & & \\
7 & 4 & 6 & 8 & 9 & 11 & 12 & 14 & & & & & & \\
8 & 5 & 8 & 11 & 11 & 13 & 14 & 16 & 18 & 19 & 20 & & & \\
9 & 6 & 9 & 12 & 14 & 15 & 17 & 18 & 20 & 22 & 23 & 24 & 25 & 27
\end{array}
Interesting observation : $c(8,2) = c(8,3)$

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbbWX.png) https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.08723

Comment: The code would be good; but more results would be even better, so people who can't run the code could also use them. I get the impression that $c(n,1)=n-2$.

Comment: @joriki  $c(6,1)\geq 5$, though.  I have $c(2n,1)\geq 3n-4$.

Comment: And $c(2n+1,1)\geq 3n-3$.

Comment: @Batominovski: I can't find the $5$ chords for $c(6,1)$; could you explain please?

Comment: @joriki Let $ABCDEF$ be a cyclic hexagon.  Draw $AC$, $BD$, $AD$, $DF$, and $EA$.

Comment: @Batominovski: Thanks. Nice, I missed that.

Comment: Is this a *convex* polygon?

Comment: @saulspatz yes and the chords can be drawn as curves

Comment: If a chord is crossed by several chords at the same point, are you counting that as separate crossings? If so, I don't think it matters whether the chords can be drawn as curves -- they either cross or they don't; you can make them cross unnecessarily by making them curved, but you can't make them not cross if they do.

Comment: @joriki yes, drawing the chords as curves does not make a difference and we count the crossing of several chords at the same point as separate crossings.

Comment: “if we choose $k$ large enough, we can always put in all $\frac{n \cdot (n-3)}{2}$ possible chords”. This is possible iff $k\ge ab$ for each $1\le a,b$ with $a+b=n-2$, that is iff $k\ge \lfloor n^2/4\rfloor-n+1$.

Comment: The sequence for row “9” is not in [OEIS](https://oeis.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You are asking about a maximal possible number of edges in an outer $k$-planar graph (minus $n$ for the number of sides of the $n$-gon). As far as I know, these graphs are a very recent topic in graph theory and they are studied in Würzburg. It is already known that an outer $1$-planar graph with $n$ vertices has at most $2.5n-4$ edges and this bound is tight [A] (that coincides with the second column of your table). But I found no results for bigger $k$,  so I have sent a link to your question to Würzburg team.

*References*

[A] C. Auer, C. Bachmaier, F. J. Brandenburg, A. Gleißner, K. Hanauer, D. Neuwirth, and J. Reislhuber. *[Outer 1-planar graphs](https://www.infosun.fim.uni-passau.de/~chris/down/Outer1Planar.pdf)*. Algorithmica, 74(4):1293-1320, 2016.

Comment: Hello Alex, this is indeed the origin of the problem and thus I am already familiar with the reference, but still thanks for that. I tried to keep the formulation of the problem more general, but in hindsight it might have been useful to also include the origin.